# The proof of an edge-analogue of the Erdos-Posa theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I have been working on RD's *Graph Theory* recently...

There are two exercises 7.23(chapter 7, ex. 23) and 9.6 asking for a proof of an edge version of the Erdos-Posa theorem, namely

*There exists a function $g$ such that every (connected) graph contains either $k$ edge-disjoint cycles or $g(k)$ edges meeting all its cycles.*

**Exercise 7.23**
Find a constant $c$ such that every graph on $n$ vertex having $n+2k(\log k+\log\log k+c)$ edges contains $k$ edge-disjoint cycles.

It's not hard to derive an edge version of the E-D theorem based on this result: taking $g(k)=2k(\log k+\log\log k+c)$ and leave a spanning tree of $G$ will remove all cycles.

**My attempts on 7.23**

We may suppress all vertices of degree $2$ and delete all vertices of degree $1$, which decreases $|E(G)|$ and $|V(G)|$ by the same amount and assume that $\delta(G)\geq 3$. We have $g(G)\leq 2\log n$ when $\delta(G)\geq 3$. However, to apply induction on $k$, we need to find an upper bound of $g(G)$ in $k$. And I am stuck here.

**Exercise 9.6** (This exercise directly asks for proof, so I present the author's hint here.) Consider in each component a normal spanning tree $T$. If $T$ has many chords $xy$, use any regular pattern of how the paths $xT y$ intersect to find many edge-disjoint cycles.

FYI: exercise 9.6 is attached to the chapter 'Ramsey theory.'

Poorly, I have no idea how to proceed with the hint.

Any related comments or references are welcome! Though almost all articles I found refer to RD's textbook (in which the hint appendix are removed) or say 'an easy analogy' :( THANKS!!!

Comment: Without having solved the problem myself, I suggest that an interesting place to start is the following special case: if you take an $n$-edge path (a special case of a normal spanning tree) and add $2k(\log k + \log \log k + c)$ edges to it, you can find $k$ edge-disjoint cycles in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just so close...

Suppose that $G$ has $n+f(k)$ edges. According to $\delta(G)\geq 3$, we have
$$n+f(k)=|E(G)|\geq \frac{n\delta(G)}{2}=\frac{3}{2}n.$$
Thus, $$g(G)=2\log n\leq 2\log 2f(k).$$
(The rest of this answer is calculation, hence not that important)

To apply induction, we need $$n+f(k)-2\log 2f(k)\geq n+f(k-1),$$ which implies that after removing a small cycle, there are enough edges to compose the other $(k-1)$ by induction hypothesis. Take $f(k)=2k(\log k+\log\log k+4)$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
&f(k)-2\log 2f(k)\\=&8k+2k\log k+2k\log\log k-2\log 4k-2\log(\log k+\log \log k +4)\\
\geq &8(k-1)+2(k-1)\log k+2(k-1)\log\log k+(4+2\log\log k-2\log(4\log k))\\
> &f(k-1).
\end{align*}
It is a quick observation that $f(k)+f(r)\geq f(k+r)$ for $k,r\geq 2$. If $G$ contains less that $k$ disjoint edge-disjoint cycles, then $|E(G)|\leq n-1+f(k)$. The observation allows us to focus on connected graph $G$. Removing $f(k)$ edges and leaving a tree will destroy all cycles.